# What is the difference between These Dependencies

Tags: magento2

What is the difference in declaring dependencies like this?

`use Magento\Catalog\Model\Category;`

`\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,`

Answer (score 0):

The first one

```
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Category;
```

can be reused later in your code without having to rewrite the whole class path everywhere. It allows you to have cleaner code in general. I would recommend using this option instead of the second one. For example :

```
function doSomething(Category $category):Category{
    $category->setName('category name');
    return $category
}

function getCategoryClassConstant(){
    return Category::CONSTANT;
}
```